Finding when expression is the square of a rational
I was trying to find when $\frac{2t+2}{-t^2 - 2t + 7}$ is the square of a rational.
First, I tried setting this equation equal to $r^2$, where r is a rational, and finding the curve it comes out to, and then seeing if I can somehow manipulate it using elliptic curves.
However, I could not do this, and I don't know if there is any other direction I can take.
If someone could help me with this, and also the same thing for the expression $\frac{t^2 - 4t +3}{-t^2 - 2t +7}$

What are the conditions on $t$? Is it supposed to be rational? integer? Real? Complex?

I'm surprised you considered elliptic curves (when there are no cubics around) without applying the quadratic formula (when we have a degree 2 polynomial). Solve for $t$ in terms of $r^2$. So if there are no conditions on $t$, then any rational $r^2$ will lead to a (possibly complex) $t$. Presuming you want rational $t$, then you just have to check that the discriminant is a perfect rational square. If I did the calculations right (but no promises), $D = 32r^4 + 4$.  $\quad$ This same approach works for your other expression. So update your question with what you've tried based on this.

There is a solution to this problem using elliptic curves as you hint. Note that upon multiplying by $(-t^2 - 2t + 7)^2$ if one has
$$u^2 = \frac{2t+2}{-t^2 - 2t + 7}$$
then it is clear that
$$(2t+2)(-t^2 - 2t + 7)$$
is a square. In particular, the problem is reduced to finding the rational points on the elliptic curve
$$u^2 = (2t + 2)(-t^2 - 2t + 7).$$
This elliptic curve has rank $1$ -- it is isomorphic to the elliptic curve with Weierstrass equation
$$E : y^2 = x^3 - 2x$$
by the isomorphism
$$(u,t) \mapsto \left( \frac{-t - 1}{2}, \frac{u}{4} \right).$$
Clearly $E$ has a rational point $P = (-1,-1)$. The point $2P=(9/4,21/8)$ is not integral or a $2$-torsion point, so must have infinite order. It is harder to show that the rank is exactly $1$, you could use Magma or Sage's implementation of descent, or try to do a $2$-isogeny descent by hand (cf. Cassel's Lectures on Elliptic curves, or Silverman's example in chapter X).
So in your original example, we can (for example) construct $t = -16297/3528$ which has
$$\frac{2t+2}{-t^2 - 2t + 7} = \left(\frac{9492}{7967}\right)^2$$
by considering $4P$ (and taking its preimage under the above isomorphism). There are infinitely many more examples.

I understand. I think the crucial part of the step is realizing that $ (2t+2)(-t^2 -2t+7)$ has to be the square of a rational.

Well in some sense that is the trivial step, but fortunately others have already proved the hard theorems in the more difficult steps.
